# SQL Server - How to reset identity column after amount of number

Tags: sql-server

I have a table "OrderInfo" with 4 columns: ID,Driver,Date,Increment_ID.

The column "Increment_ID" is identity from 1 to 9999.
The column "ID" based on value of the column "Increment_ID".(Ex: M-ddMMyy-0001).

Like you can see the format value of column "ID", "ddMMyy" is day, month and year.
For example: Today is 25/01/2018 so the value of my column "ID" is: M-251218-0001.

I have created a trigger to reset identity column (Increment_ID) if its value reach 9999. But something went wrong and I couldn't insert new row unless I dropped that trigger. Here is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_OrderInfo_ResetIdentityColumn ON OrderInfo
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @max_increment_ID int = (SELECT MAX(od.Increment_ID) FROM OrderInfo od inner join inserted i on i.Increment_ID = od.Increment_ID )
    IF(@max_increment_ID is not null and @max_increment_ID=9999)
      DBCC CHECKIDENT ('OrderInfo',RESEED,0)
END
```

For make sure to prevent duplicate primary key "ID" I chose the max value for "Increment_ID" is 9999. Actually I just have about 7000 rows a day.

I will be grateful for any help from everyone. Thank you!

Comment: Once you reach the max value, unless you delete rows from the table, `MAX(Increment_ID)` will always find that top value and perform another reseed attempt. I'd usually recommend though - if you care about the *numeric* values of an identity column, you're probably using the wrong tool.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So I will write a delete statement if I reach the max value 9999 and then I will reset my identity column? Am I wrong?

Comment: @MitchWheat can you give me a example?.

Comment: If you want the values to cycle from 1 through 9999, use a [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql) instead. If you must reset it every day, use a scheduled job with `ALTER SEQUENCE .. RESTART`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Thank you for your info. Schedule job is a solution for my case. But I just wanted to use store procedure or trigger to solve my issue. Your solution is the best way to solve the big project with SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need make sure the ID is unique,could use the [data] as one condition

```
if Not Exist(select 1 FROM OrderInfo where [date]=getdate())
    DBCC CHECKIDENT ('OrderInfo',RESEED,0)
```

Comment: Thank you your solution. I left the condition if and variable @max_increment_ID and use CONVERT keyword to convert the date column in my table and compare with the current date. If there is no row matches I will delete all rows in my table and set identity to 0.